# esb mule passing the parameters to the method via http

Tags: esb, mule

I have a test method:

```
@Test
    public void testHello_with_muleXmlConfig() throws Exception {

        MuleClient client = new MuleClient("mule-config-test.xml");
        client.getMuleContext().start();

        MuleMessage result = client.send("http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello", "some data", null);
        assertNotNull(result);

        assertNull(result.getExceptionPayload());
        assertFalse(result.getPayload() instanceof NullPayload);

        assertEquals("hello", result.getPayloadAsString());
    }
```

Here (client.send("http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello", "some data", null)), I'm passing the parameter/data = 'some data'.

And I have a class:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public String sayHello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

which is exposed as spring bean in mule-config.xml:

```
<spring:bean id="helloWorld" class="org.mule.application.hello.HelloWorld"/>

<flow name="HelloWorld">
        <inbound-endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello"/>
        <invoke method="sayHello" object-ref="helloWorld"/>
    </flow>
```

What I should do to pass the parameter 'hello' into the 'sayHello()' method. If just changing it to 'sayHello(String text)' - it will not work.

Comment: What parameter "hello"? You're talking about sending "some data": isn't "some data" what you would expect to be passed to `sayHello(String text)`?

Comment: yes, I want to pass 'some data'

Answer (score 4):

You need to add this to the invoke element:

```
methodArguments="#[message.getPayload()]" methodArgumentTypes="java.lang.String"
```

Comment: Nice one! You'd rather use a MEL expression BTW: `"#[message.payload]"`. (As a side note, I still prefer `component` than `invoke`, the latter feels to much like "programming in XML" :P).

Comment: after I put:   <invoke method="sayHello" object-ref="helloWorld" methodArguments="#[message.getPayload()]" methodArgumentTypes="java.lang.String" />

I have exceptions like this: ionException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Single method "sayHello", with "0" arguments not found on "org.mule.application.hello.HelloWorld@24be0446"
 at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:115)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about how/if `invoke` works: I suggest you use `component` instead.

If you change your method to accept a `String`, like for example:

```
public String sayHello(final String text)
{
    return "hello:" + text;
}
```

then you also need to use an `object-to-string-transformer` to deserialize the inbound input stream to a String:

```
<flow name="HelloWorld">
    <inbound-endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello" />
    <object-to-string-transformer />
    <component>
        <spring-object bean="helloWorld" />
    </component>
</flow>
```

Comment: after this, I have: ionException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Single method "sayHello", with "0" arguments not found on "org.mule.application.hello.HelloWorld@6d3d7254"
 at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:115)

Comment: Works fine for me when testing with `client.send("http://<host:port>/hello", "some data", null)`. Did you use that command too?

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce your problem: the above configuration works perfectly fine for me. Are you sure you've deployed the above config on the Mule you're testing?

Comment: I'm going to work on it today. Will update this post later, will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

- add this in your flow :

```html
<invoke object-ref="helloWorld" method="sayHello" methodArguments="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.name]" doc:name="Invoke" />
```

- and this is the invoked method :

  public String sayHello(String name) {
          return String.format("Hello %s!", name);
      }